# Power Query Editor (Excel) - error handling no data in API feed

Tags: json, excel, api, powerquery

I have an API feed into excel that works well but occasionally when there is no data in the JSON API Feed, I receive an error box which then stops the excel feed from working when the API data does return.
I've tried various error handling with no success (the error is 'We cannot convert a value of type Record to type List' - caused due to no data).  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

API feed when no data:

```
{"data" : [{}] }
```

Current code:

```
   let
    Source = try Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://link.com/link.json"))
    otherwise {"1","2","3"},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), 1, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"cola", "colb", "colc"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{{"Column1.cola", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.colb", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.colc", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1.cola", "A"}, {"Column1.colb", "B"}, {"Column1.colc", "C"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: I think the `try ... otherwise ...` might be too early, since `Json.Document` and `Web.Contents` probably aren't where the error occurs. It's likely the error occurs during the `Table.FromList`, since it expects a list but is being given a record when there is no data. Two questions: #1 What do you want table to look like when there is no data? #2 What does the feed's response look like when there is data? (Sensitive/private content from the feed can be replaced, it's just the structure that's needed to give an answer.)

Comment: Also, it might be possible for you to make use of`Table.FromRecords` (instead of `Table.FromList` and `Table.ExpandRecordColumn`).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  The `try ... otherwise ...'`  deals with when the feed drops completely i.e. a drop of network connection.  You are correct the problem is the next section - the feed is received but contains no data.  I tried the FromRecords but still the same problem unfortunately.  I could do another `try otherwise` but having no success how to deal with the `othewise` part

Comment: When the feed has no data, I just need an empty table i.e. no pop-up error message.  The feed with no data is `{"data" : [{}] }` and the error message received is "[Expression.Error] We cannot convert a value of type Record to type List".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem with 2 try statements:

1. The first one deals with errors when the network connection drops.
2. The second one deals deals with errors when the feed is working but contains no data (the solution creates a table with an empty
   row).

   ```
   let
   Source = try Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://link.com/link.json"))
   otherwise {"1","2","3"},
   #"Converted to Table" = try Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), 1, null, ExtraValues.Error) otherwise Table.FromList({"1"}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), 1, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
   #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"cola", "colb", "colc"}),
   #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column1",{{"Column1.cola", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.colb", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.colc", Int64.Type}}),
   #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1.cola", "A"}, {"Column1.colb", "B"}, {"Column1.colc", "C"}}) 
   in 
   #"Renamed Columns"
   ```